# Android Lock Screen appears behind home screen occasionally

Tags: android, android-activity, wallpaper, lockscreen, homescreen

Android 4+

We're developing a lock screen app (not a widget). The app listens for SCREEN_OFF, and generates the activity, so that when SCREEN_ON is received, the user sees the activity in front of the security features using FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED.

We've found that on rare occasions around 1 in every 50 to 100 times, the activity appears behind the Home screen rather than in front of the lock screen. We cannot replicate the issue, and it doesn't appear to happen when connected for debugging (I've sat and locked/unlocked my phone and not seen it, then taken the cable out and it happens in the next few times).

The activity appears to display over the wallpaper, with the home screen icons over the top of the activity.

3 questions:

1) Is it possible to "listen" for when the home screen gets started so that we could just finish() the activity at that point?
2) Is it possible to ensure that the activity runs over the lock screen all the time?
3) How would you test this to try to replicate the fault? I cannot figure out why it does it at all and cannot replicate it.

TIA

Comment: We're experiencing this as well with a lock screen app we are developing. Did you find a workaround for the issue? Thanks!

Comment: try to set high priority to the intent filter of your broadcast receiver as mentioned [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/intent-filter-element.html) . `android:priority="999"`